# How to tile a bitmap with DirectComposition or Windows.UI.Composition

Tags: windows, direct2d, direct-composition

How do I create a tiled image background using the compositor API?

D2D bitmap brushes have [`SetExtendModeX/Y`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1bitmapbrush-setextendmodex), but [`CompositionSurfaceBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.compositionsurfacebrush) don't seem to have an equivalent.

[`TileEffect`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects_TileEffect.htm) is marked "NoComposition".

I'd like to avoid creating screen-sized sufraces and tiling "manually" (i.e. with D2D).

Answer (score 0):

[`BorderEffect`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects_BorderEffect.htm) is what I was looking for. It works with composition and supports the same extend modes as a D2D bitmap brush.